# Kernel Panics Unable to mount rootfs, HELP

Tags: boot, kernel, raid, initramfs, mdadm

Hej, I need some serious help, I recently updated to 22.04.

I'm not unable to start server with out getting this error.
I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 with no issues so am surprised I now got this.

This is using a mdadm lvm raid as boot drive.

```
VFS: Cannot open device "mapper/porkchop--vg-root" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 8 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.3.0.28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu
Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/WS C422 PRO_SE, BIOS 3301 09/04/2020
Call Trace:
 dump_stack+0x6d/0x95
 panic+0xfe/0x2d4
 mount_block_root+0x1f4/0x2db
 ? set_debug_rodata+0x17/0x17
 mount_root+0x38/0x3a
 prepare_namespace+0x139/0x18e
 kernel_init_freeable+0x245/0x26d
 ? rest_init+0xb0 /0xb0
 kernel_init+0xe/0x110
 ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Kernel Offset: 0x19e00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount roof fs on unknown-block(0x0) ]---
```

There is only one kernel on the system 5.3.0.28 I got the same error when loading that from GRUB.

EDIT-
I added a m2 drive that I had laying around and did a fresh install on this system. I installed mdadm and was able to mount my raid. I am guessing the upgrade to 22 caused that issue where it can not find the raid.
So my next question is how do I repair this from the raid drive side. when I run
`nano /mnt/raid/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`
i get:

```
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=c11e32e6:20e26be5:1faa0919:6acc2e41
ARRAY /dev/md/VROC container=c11e32e6:20e26be5:1faa0919:6acc2e41 member=0 UUID=c3aa6aef:47391270:446f2201:eaed6553
```

Comment: Please clarify what kernel your Ubuntu 22.04 system is using.

Comment: 5.3.0.28-generix

Comment: That is not the kernel that comes with 22.04 by default.